# Is there a way in python to detect if a domain does not exist or error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-requests

i want to ask whether or not if it's possible to detect a website that isn't available or a website can't be reach in python?
[image: Odoo]

And there is also a site where it says "The site can't be reached", and when checking the network it says status "(Failed)"

[image: Status failed]

To detect a site i used this code.

```
import requests

exist=[]

for b in Phishing:
    try:
        request = requests.get(b)
        if request.status_code == 200:
            exist.append(b)
            print('Exist')
        elif request.status_code == 204:
            print('user does not exist')
        elif request.status_code == 304:
            print('Not available')
        elif request.status_code == 504:
            print('Timeout')
        elif request.status_code == (failed):
            print('failed')
    except:
        print('Not Exist')
```

So far the code that i used to detect a website is this. I'm open for suggestion on how to improve the code.

Thank you!

Comment: Generally, 2xx codes indicate success - 204 certainly does *not* mean "user does not exist", normally a 204 would indicate a successful response that does not have to be rendered (classic example is clicking a 'save' button, where the only response whether or not it succeeded). There's a good overview of http status codes here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: Are you seeking to determine if the FQDN is valid or if the website is accessible?

Comment: `requests.get()` is looking for a _webserver_ at that address.  It's certainly possible that the _host_ exists, but is not running a _webserver_.

Comment: @Grismar i forgot to erase that, there's a specific code that i used, where a special url can be get through checking networks url location, from there is shows a link and status code from the network if the status is 204, and it works.

Comment: @DavidMoruzzi If it's possible both of them

Answer (score 0):

In general, if `requests.get()` throws a `ConnectionError` exception, then the hostname does not exist, or is unreachable, or is not serving a website.

Otherwise if `requests.get()` does not throw an exception (regardless of the specific http return code), then a website does exist at that address.

Comment: Yes, that's why it's quite annoying, even if put status_code = 200, there is still some way a site that can't be reached get's through the requests. For example the 2nd picture. for odoo I know it's much harder to detect, but if there's a special way to know that odoo site does not exist without the help of requests, I'm up for suggestions.

Comment: @TheBotHunter if a 0-byte response (which is valid) is not desired, then the following: `if len(requests.get(site).content) > 0: print(f'Site with content: {site}')`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests

sites_to_be_evaluated = [
    'http://example.com',
    'http://example.net',
    'http://example.gov'
]

sites_accessible = []
valid_dns = []

for site in sites_to_be_evaluated:
    try:
        fqdn = site.split('//')[1] # remove before // 
        fqdn = fqdn.split('/')[0] # remove anything after /
        if requests.get(f'https://dns.google/resolve?name={fqdn}&type=ANY').json()['Status'] == 0:
            valid_dns.append(fqdn)
        if requests.get(site).status_code == 200:  # 200 is the status code for a successful request
            sites_accessible.append(site)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        pass

print(f'The following sites are accessible: {sites_accessible}')
>> The following sites are accessible: ['http://example.com', 'http://example.net']
print(f'The following sites have valid DNS: {valid_dns}')
>> The following sites have valid DNS: ['example.com', 'example.net']
```

Just because a site is returns a 200 OK does not mean the site is useful. It may be a parked website that contains nothing more than advertisements. Likewise, if the website is unresponsive - that only indicates that the requester cannot receive a respond. You may need to evaluate with a [tracert](http://speedtest-sfld.merit.edu/toolkit/gui/reverse_traceroute.cgi) to determine network paths.

If you use Google's DNS API service, please read their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/isp) and respect their infrastructure.

Comment: Is there a reason on why u used Google's DNS API service? @DavidMoruzzi

Comment: @TheBotHunter To meet your comment "If it's possible both of them" when asked if FQDN or website accessibility should be checked for validity.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but is the google DNS API used to search a site that uses google as a web host? I think right now detecting a parked website is really hard to crack, so i'm probably going to skip on that.

Comment: Domain Name System (DNS) is used to resolve domains to IP addresses. Google provides an accessible resolver (dns.google) that may be queried programmatically. Amazon provides an excellent explanation of [DNS here](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/what-is-dns/).